# Trouble removing from linked list in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, singly-linked-list

I have a function that removes from a linked list. Each node in the linked list is a dynamically created struct. To remove, I pass a data value in that I would like to search for in the list of nodes. If one of those nodes contains that data, I want to remove the entire node containing that data. It appears like they get added fine, but whenever I remove, the size variable decrements but the nodes are still in the list.

In Mag.h:

```
struct ListNode 
{
    int* data;
    ListNode* nextNode;
};

class Mag 
{
private:
    ListNode* head;
public:
    Mag();
    Mag(Mag& mag);
    Mag &operator= (const Mag &);
    ~Mag();
    int size;
    void add(const int&);
    void remove(const int&);
    void printList();
    };
}
```

I add nodes to the list like this:

```
// adds to front of list
void Mag::add(int const &num) 
{
    Node* new_data = new ListNode();
    new_data->data = num;
    new_data->next = head;
    head = newNode;

    size++;
}
```

Now here's how I remove them (probably the issue):

```
void Mag::remove(int const &num) 
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    int look_for = num;
    ListNode* searchFor = head;
    int count = 0;
    count = size;

    if (count != 0) 
    {
        do 
        {
            if (searchFor->data == look_for) 
            {
                ListNode* delete_node = new ListNode;
                delete_node = searchFor;
                searchFor = searchFor->next;

                size--;
                delete delete_node;
                return;
            }

            searchFor = searchFor->next;
            count--;

        } while (count != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a new node and store its address in `delete_node`, then you leak this node and copy the address of another node into `delete_node`. `searchFor` is a local variable, so changing the node it points to has no effect on your list, except for the fact you then delete the node it points to.